# Is it worth upgrading my desktop PC?

Tags: laptop, desktop-computer

I'm thinking about upgrading my desktop PC. It's 3 years old, and I mostly used it for programming, a bit of gaming and things like that. I had no problems with it, it can run the newest games, not at full settings but it can. But now as I'm going to attend university, I'm thinking about giving a boost to it.

Specs:

- Intel Core I5 3330 CPU
- Sapphire Radeon HD 7770 GPU
- 8GB Corsair Vengance 1600MHZ DDR3 RAM
- 120GB Samsung 850EVO SSD
- 500GB WD 7200RPM HDD
- Asrock B75Pro3 motherboard
- 500W PSU
- Extra: 8 yo. 1440x900 LG Flatron monitor

I would like to do modeling, and game development as well, because I have these options at university too, and still can't decide what should I learn.

Additional info: I have a "work/travel" notebook as well which has the following specs:

- Intel Core i5-6200U CPU
- 4GB DDR3 1333MHz (I'm not sure, and I think it's not really enough for anything big)
- Nvidia GT920M GPU
- 500GB 5400RPM HDD
- screen resolution is somewhat below my desktop

I'm awaiting ideas about if I should upgrade and if yes, then what parts are the most important. Or if I should sell the desktop then why, what should I buy from the money from selling it, etc.

Comment: This will be closed as "primarily opinion based", but imho this is a fine rig for light programming work. It will struggle with modern games though. I'd replace the graphics card. (Or keep it all and get another monitor)

Answer (score 1):

Once you decide about what kind of topics you want to learn you'll have to install and test dev / other tools.
Only then you will understand if your pc's power is enough or not for your tasks.
IMHO the only thing I would prefer not to work with is the small monitor with the vintage resolution.

Check what you want to do first and then understand what you want to improve, decision will be easier then.

Comment: So you say, i should buy  aew monitor then? :)

Comment: This is just my personal impression (I just work with 2x24" fullHD monitors and at home a have a single 24" fullHD), it doesn't mean that is mandatory for your needs.
On the other hand, reading about the tasks you'll be up to it is almost impossible to be into development comfortably with that kind of monitor / resolution.
My two cents :)

If you buy a new monitor be sure that you can lift it up or down in order to be sure to put it in the right height in front of your eyes so you will not have neck pain / other issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't had any problems yet, I would invest carefully. If you want to test how well your PC performs for 3D modeling, you might want to look at [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) which can be downloaded completely free of charge [here](https://www.blender.org/download/) and find a [complex scene to render](https://www.blender.org/download/demo-files/).

## RAM

As you have found out from your comments, RAM is especially important when doing development work (plus it is relatively cheap =) )

This would be my first investment since many SDK/General virtual machines and software used for the actual creation of a final program (modeling, image work, video/audio etc.) aren't often as CPU/GPU bound as the final program code itself. In your particular case, with a virtual (phone or os) environment, this is particularly memory intensive. For your setup, I would double the memory if possible. Though 16GB might be overkill, there will be (potentially) some programs that make really effective use of it.

Regardless of any other upgrade, I would make this one first.

---

## GPU

I would consider the GPU next, since this could effect things like 3D modeling. Regardless, if you need to test something (especially unoptimized code), you will want (in general) a more powerful card. Consumer cards aren't as good as workstation cards for some tasks related to 3D modeling, but they should be sufficient for what you will be likely doing at university.

## CPU

I would spec out possibly some CPUs (assuming there is anything in your price range/ability to upgrade to). While not the end-all, be-all having quicker execution of your programs will likely be helpful at some stage.

## Miscellaneous

- A larger storage drive. 500GB might become pretty small, pretty quick if you start installing SDKs and assets for program development.
- Bigger monitor. Programming and graphics tools tend to have large layouts (lots of options and items) and detachable panels. Plus, if you purchase a new monitor, you may be able to attach your old one as a second desktop. For development work, two monitors are just the bees knees.
- Power supply. Not a biggie, but if you get a better card, you may need it.